# Django Parler "The 'language_code' attribute cannot be changed directly

Tags: django, translation, django-cms, django-parler, django-translated-fields

I am currently extending a plugin to play well with Django translations and languages. Here is the method in question. Prior to getting translations involved, it worked as needed.

I extended the query to pull data from a couple of translation tables. However, I am getting an error, which I am unsure how to deal with.

```
    def get_authors_and_article_counts(self, authors):
        """method returning authors and their article counts"""

        # first, we collect ids of authors for which we need to get data
        author_ids = [author.id for author in self.authors.all()]
        author_ids_tuple_str = '(' +  str(author_ids).strip('[]') + ')'

        #limit subquery to published articles
        published_clause = """ AND
            is_published %s AND
            publishing_date <= %s
            """ % (SQL_IS_TRUE, SQL_NOW_FUNC, )

        query = """
                with article_count as (
                  select author_id, count(*) as article_count
                    from aldryn_newsblog_article
                   where app_config_id = 1
                    %s
                   group by author_id
                )

                select distinct prof.*, coalesce(ac.article_count, 0) as article_count, author_trans.*, aldryn_people_trans.slug
                from common_authorprofile prof

                left join article_count ac
                on ac.author_id = prof.profile_id

                left join common_authorprofile_translation author_trans
                on prof.id = author_trans.master_id

                left join aldryn_people_person_translation aldryn_people_trans
                on prof.profile_id = aldryn_people_trans.master_id
                WHERE
                        prof.id IN %s AND
                        author_trans.language_code = 'ru';

""" % (published_clause, author_ids_tuple_str)

        print(query)
        #print(author_ids)

        raw_authors = list(AuthorProfile.objects.raw(query))
        #print(raw_authors)
        authors = [author for author in raw_authors if author.article_count]

        print(authors)
        return sorted(authors, key=lambda x: x.article_count, reverse=True)
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner                                          
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in _get_response                                      
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
core/handlers/base.py", line 154, in _get_response                                      
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/response.py", line 106, in render                                              
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content                                     
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render                                        
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/base.py", line 171, in render                                                  
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/base.py", line 163, in _render                                                 
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/base.py", line 937, in render                                                  
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated                                        
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/classyt
ags/core.py", line 153, in render                                                       
    return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sekizai
/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py", line 93, in render_tag                                  
    rendered_contents = nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/base.py", line 937, in render                                                  
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated                                        
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/classyt
ags/core.py", line 153, in render                                                       
    return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cms/tem
platetags/cms_tags.py", line 447, in render_tag                                         
    return toolbar.render_with_structure(context, nodelist)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cms/too
lbar/toolbar.py", line 477, in render_with_structure                                    
    rendered_contents = nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/base.py", line 937, in render                                                  
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated                                        
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/classyt
ags/core.py", line 153, in render                                                       
    return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cms/tem
platetags/cms_tags.py", line 313, in render_tag                                         
    nodelist=nodelist,
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cms/plu
gin_rendering.py", line 343, in render_page_placeholder                                 
    nodelist=None,
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cms/plu
gin_rendering.py", line 259, in render_placeholder                                      
    placeholder_content = ''.join(plugin_content)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cms/plu
gin_rendering.py", line 456, in render_plugins                                          
    yield self.render_plugin(plugin, context, placeholder, editable)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cms/plu
gin_rendering.py", line 429, in render_plugin                                           
    context = plugin.render(context, instance, placeholder.slot)
  File "/home/user/sites/app-web/app/apps/plugins/cms_plugins.py", line 1
8, in render                                                                            
    authors_list = instance.get_authors_and_article_counts(request)
  File "/home/user/sites/app-web/app/apps/plugins/models.py", line 88, in
 get_authors_and_article_counts                                                         
    raw_authors = list(AuthorProfile.objects.raw(query))
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
db/models/query.py", line 1339, in __iter__                                             
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
db/models/query.py", line 1326, in _fetch_all                                           
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
db/models/query.py", line 1368, in iterator                                             
    setattr(instance, column, values[pos])
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/parler/
fields.py", line 161, in __set__                                                        
    raise AttributeError("The 'language_code' attribute cannot be changed directly! Use t
he set_current_language() method instead.")                                             
AttributeError: The 'language_code' attribute cannot be changed directly! Use the set_cur
rent_language() method instead.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the problem here `raw_authors = list(AuthorProfile.objects.raw(query))`? Should I be doing something like `MyModel.objects.language('en'). ...`, run the query via Parler after changing the query to discard the parts dealing with translations? What is the proper way?

Comment: Are you using `django-translated-fields`? Why did you tag `django-translated-fields`?

Comment: @SpeedyMatch, I don't know what that is. It seemed like it is relevant here because, well, because the issue seems to be related to Django translated fields.

Answer (score 1):

Before we moving on to solution let's discuss why this error happened.

We can perform django raw query in 2 ways either using **`Model.objects.raw()`** or **execute custom raw query directly**.
When we say:

1. `Model.objects.raw()` ⇾ it basically perform raw queries and return model instances.
2. directly custom raw query ⇾ In this case, you can always access the database directly, routing around the model layer entirely.

For your case `list(AuthorProfile.objects.raw(query))` during this it fetch result successfully but the error happens when it tries to make `model instance`....

From your traceback: *File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/
db/models/query.py", line 1368, in iterator*
`setattr(instance, column, values[pos])`

...because this **instance doesn't allow to set the attribute**.
see below [codebase](https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler/blob/080815d9cf404c57be0946b4f0afc7d2ca8b09ce/parler/fields.py#L188) of django-parler

```
class LanguageCodeDescriptor(object):
    ..... some code ....
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        raise AttributeError("The 'language_code' attribute cannot be changed directly! Use the set_current_language() method instead.")
    ..... some code ....
```

Coming back to your answer. There are couple of ways you can follow.

1. Just remove the exception from `LanguageCodeDescriptor` method `__set__`. changes in django-parler like this of course this is not recommended.
2. I would like to consider your suggestion `MyModel.objects.language('en')`. your query seems little bit more complex try to use `ORM` if possible, if not possible just follow points 3.
3. Execute raw query using method 2 from discussed above i.e directly custom raw query,

   ```
   from django.db import connection
   with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      cursor.execute(query, [published_clause, author_ids_tuple_str])
      rows = cursor.fetchall()
   ```

**NOTE:** if you use method 3 then you can not access model_instance like this `author.article_count` since this method doesn't return model instance.

The following links can be followed for more details:

[performing raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/)

[django-parler codebase](https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler/blob/master/parler/fields.py)

Comment: Thank you. So, it seems that option 3 is really my only choice then? Is there no way of making this work without going so low-level in abstraction?

Comment: I don't know much details about django-parler, may be there are some ways to override class method(currently which raise AttributeError) in efficient way. You should try option 2 I think raw query can be converted to ORM. Is there any tables used in query which not belongs to ORM?

Comment: I think all the tables that are used are either directly pertaining to specific models I have or their translations. There are no other types of tables in the query. I have been trying to figure out how to do the query via ORM :/